# How do I use homomorphism theorem to show the assertion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2-3,2x+4 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[\sqrt 3]$. I tried to use first homomorphism theorem, but not able to get that how should I approach.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb Z_2[\sqrt{3}]$? If by $\Bbb Z_2$ you mean $\Bbb F_2$, $3 = 1$, so $\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{1}$, and "both" square roots of $1$ already exist in $\Bbb F_2$ ($x^2 - 1 = (x - 1)^2$ in $\Bbb F_2[x]$).

Answer (score 4):

First, note that $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 - 3,2x + 4)\cong\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/(2\sqrt{3} + 4)$. Next, we see that $I = (2\sqrt{3} + 4) = (2(\sqrt{3} + 2))$, and that $\sqrt{3} + 2$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$: $(\sqrt{3} + 2)(-\sqrt{3} + 2) = -3 + 4 = 1$. Thus,
$$
\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/I \cong\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/(2)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x^2 - 3)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2 - 3)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2 - 1)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/(x - 1)^2\cong \Bbb F_2[x]/(x)^2.
$$